# Products specs in admin panel spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, spree, rspec-rails

I've got some piece of specs code:
https://gist.github.com/mPanasiewicz/9751c1de65e9920d8ad6d6f866ef0ae5
there is the problem because I get 302 code instead of 200 or 404(if sth went wrong). I think 302 because it redirects me.

```
require 'rails_helper'

    RSpec.describe Spree::Admin::ProductsController, type: :controller do
      describe 'GET synchronize' do
        stub_authorization!
        let!(:variant) { create(:variant) }

    it 'updates @products pkb starpacks details' do
      spree_get :synchronize, id: variant
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end

    it 'returns record not found if product not exist' do
      spree_get :synchronize, id: 0
      expect(response).to have_http_status(404)
    end
  end
end
```

I've got 'stub_authorization!' but I think it doesn't work 
Any ideas what is wrong with my code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `redirect_to` method in your `update` method. Redirect responds to `302` code. If you want get code `200` you should use `render` method instead `redirect_to`, but it's bad idea after update. So in your example everything works good. Go ahead, and change your `200` on `302` or:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to 'your_url'
```

Comment: My method looks like this:
https://gist.github.com/mPanasiewicz/a78e30ca620a76d26c18fec1b54ffa3a
and there is no redirect(or I missed sth from spree gem). ofc I `class_eval` the controller. In my opinion spree redirects me because of admin authorization. But as you see, I skipped this ...

Comment: The response body is:
       `Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/pl/products> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/pl/admin/products>.`
It redirects me because of authorization was not skipped(but I did it).